# How can I get most recent time in a Postgres transaction

Tags: postgresql

I noticed that Postgres caches the value of `NOW()` inside a transaction, e.g.:

```sql
lev=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
lev=# SELECT now();
              now
-------------------------------
 2022-04-07 19:16:52.358923-07
(1 row)

lev=# SELECTpg_sleep(1);
 pg_sleep
----------

(1 row)

lev=# SELECT now();
              now
-------------------------------
 2022-04-07 19:16:52.358923-07
(1 row)
```

Is there a way to get up-to-date time inside a transaction for every call to `NOW()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT), `now()` (and the standard compliant `current_timestamp`) returns the time at the start of the transaction (and is an alias for `transaction_timestamp()`)

If you want something that is independent of the statement or transaction start, use `clock_timestamp()`